# file not found in the system, creating and reading from it pass success java

Tags: java, filereader, filewriter

there is a code that write to a file by given a name.
there is a hash map that read form it.
thew writing is passing successful, also reading from it.

but the file is no where to be found.

here is the code that writes:

```
public void attachUrlToGuid(String url, String guid) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    fileList.put(url, guid);// doesn't matter if url already exist or have a different guid - just replacing with the new value.
    try{
        fileWriter = new FileWriter(fileName);
        mapper.writeValue(fileWriter, fileList);
    }
    catch (IOException e){//in case of failure and the file did not get updated, then in the next upload file it will be written due to keeping HM alive.
        LOGGER.error(ERROR_MSG_WRITE_TO_FILE);
    }
}
```

and here is the reading:

```
static{
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try{
        fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
        fileList = mapper.readValue(fileReader, HashMap.class);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e){//in case file does not exist
        fileList = new HashMap<String, String>();
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        LOGGER.error(ERROR_MSG_INVALID_DATA);
    }
}
```

care to explain?

Answer (score 0):

just check with `new File(url).exists();`

Comment: I want to be able to open the file locally later on so it will not help me. 10x.